# preg_match does not work PHP 5.5 and $nick

Tags: php

a i need your help to this form ..a try and try not work

**this is the in.php** form is the index.php the probles is here **in.php**

```
///////////////////////////////////////
        header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">';
        echo'<html>';
        echo'<head>';
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Pragma\" content=\"no-cache\" />";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"no-cache\" content=\"no-cache\" />";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Cache-Control\" content=\"no-cache\" />";
        echo"<title> Enter $_time</title>";
        echo'<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>';
        echo"<link rel='shortcut icon' href='fevicon.ico' />";
        echo'</head>';
        echo'<body>';

        echo"<div class='logo' align='center'><b>xat</b></div>";

        if ($c1 == "1")
        {
        echo "<div class=errnotice>* Capcha Not Match.!</div>";
        echo "<div class='body'><a href=\"index.php\">Re Enter</a></div>";
        }
        if ($c1 == "0")
        {


 if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9\!]/", $nick))
    {
    echo "<div class='errnotice'><b>Invalid Characters!</b></div>";
    echo"<div class='body'>Please use A-Z/0-9 Characters in Nick Special Symbol not Allowed.</div>";
    }
    else {
    if(strlen($nick)<3
        {
        echo "<div class='errnotice'>Use minimum 4 charactor in nick</div>";
        }
        else
        {
        if (isset($_COOKIE["inactive"]))
        {
        echo" <div class='errnotice'><b>YOUR IP NAME BLOCKED FOR 6 DAYS DUE TO ABUSING AND SPAMING!!</b></div>";
        }

        else
        {

        if($nick!=="") {
        $update = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$px.$utable."` WHERE nick ='".$nick."'"));
        if($update[0]!=="0") {
        echo "<div class='errnotice'>Plz Take a Diffrent Nick</div>";
        echo "<div class='body'><a href=\"index.php\">Re Enter</a></div>"; } else {
        if($g=="m") { $gg=Male; } else { $gg=Female; }
        if($sm=="1") { $smm=Yes; } else { $smm=No; }
        @mysql_query("insert into `".$px.$utable."` values(0,'$nick','$sm','$g','$a','".time()."','$room','".getenv(HTTP_USER_AGENT)."','0','$c','".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."','$ci');");
        echo "<div class='inmenubox'>Welcome </div>";
        echo"<div class='inbox'>";
        echo "<div class='body2'><img src='enter.gif' alt='enter'><B>$nick</b></div>";
```

line 51 error preg_mach and $nick
this problem only php 5.3 and 5.5 ....work fine in php 5.2

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Some indentation would have been nice...

Comment: It looks like you have a HTML tag in your PHP sections. `<b> if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9\!]/", $nick))`. Try `echo`ing it.

Comment: You can't have `<b>` in the middle of PHP code like that.

Comment: yes tanks i try echo no work retun error echo "<div class='errnotice'>Use minimum 4 charactor in nick</div>";

Comment: this is the php error in the server

Answer (score 0):

replace the line

```
  `<b>` if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9\!]/", $nick))
```

by

```
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9\!]/", $nick))
```

and check once.

Comment: sorry rakesh yes the code origina is if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9\!]/", $nick))  but the error is this in the server............PHP Warning:  preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 28 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\in.php on line 52

Comment: please you cant help a try and try :( the web es here you cant see www.zerv2.com and try come inside ... the php version is 5.3 and apache 2.2 os centos 6 an zpanel ...i change other no work

Comment: and this in server iss 6 no work error ...http://ec2-52-10-126-167.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/